# "Overflow: hidden" and fill "absolute" children

Tags: html, css, css-position, overflow

I have a problem with my video overlay block. [This bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4m5T.png) apears in every block, whitch has `overflow: hidden` and filled children with `position: absolute`. If i attach to borders absolute div or pseudo-element, there are 1px or less space between border and absolute block. How can i fix that? The bug break many animations on page.

I tried to set `top: -1px`, `left: -1px` , `right: -1px`, but it doesn't work,

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}
.children {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: white
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="children"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks Like you haven't added box-sizing:border-box in your CSS try to add *{box-sizing:border-box} can you check once

Comment: Thank you, but `box-sizing:border-box` is set

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem caused by how browsers handle subpixel rendering and rounding. You can try using the `transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);` CSS property on the absolute element:

```css
.parent {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.children {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: white;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); /* Add this line */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i really appreciate it:) But it doesn't work for me